# That text area of nullness

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem and it's been frustrating me for the past few hours. I can't seem to find anything related; perhaps I'm not being specific enough, as I'm not sure how to word it correctly, or it's a strangely unique problem.

There's a form a user fills in to update their account information, everything works as it should, except for one text area. This text areas' (which is bound to the property `Comments` of `UserInfo`) value becomes null once the form is POSTed. The `Comments` property is the only property which is null.

**When It Occurs**
A) No existing value, user inputs a value, property is null.
B) Existing value, user does/doesn't change something/anything, property is null.

I'll only include the relevant code to keep things clean and simple. Hopefully it's enough.

**Controller Actions**

```
public ActionResult Edit_Information(long id)
{
    // Get user info from the database.
    // Return the view with the user info from the DB etc.
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit_Information(long id, UserInfo userInfo)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Invalid
        return View(userInfo);
    }

    // Update the information in the DB.

    // Redirect the user back to their account.
}
```

**Razor View HTML**

```
<div style="width: 700px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left">
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Comments)
</div>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_EditorSmiles.cshtml")
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments, new { @class = "EditorArea profile-comments" })
```

`UserInfo` **Model**

```
[Validator(typeof(UserInfoValidator))]
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Comments { get;set; }
}
```

Yes, I do use FluentValidation on the model. I removed it to see if it was the cause, but it wasn't.

**Things I've Tried**

- On the POST action, I've used `FormCollection formCollection` instead of `UserInfo userInfo`.
- Threw an exception on the POST action to prove the value becomes null when posted.
- Created a new property with a different name.
- Manually gave the property a value before returning the view. The value became null when it was posted.
- Manually gave the property a value in the POST action to prove it wasn't the DB or SQL. This worked.
- Removed the Fluent Validation attribute from the model (as said above).
- Used `[Bind(Prefix = "")]` before `UserInfo userInfo`. This didn't change anything.

It's frustrated me to the point where I have to ask: What the hell is going? Am I doing something wrong? I must be overlooking something. There is another text area on the page which works as it should. It's just the text area for `Comments` which always returns null values regardless of the conditions.

Comment: Take out type UserInfo - just have a comments parameter. Is it populated? Is comments in the form ( and you see it posted in Fiddler)?

Comment: Done. Comments exists in the form (at least I assume it is). It's still null. I'm not familiar with Fiddler, in fact, I've never heard of it.

Comment: Maybe a super stupid question, but are you sure the "comments" part you posted here is included inside the correct form tag? Or maybe you have a name collision in your view?

Comment: Just to test, set UserInfo as the model type and use EditorForModel() to render the form, is the data bound for all properties then?

Comment: @Iridio: I'm 100% positive it is correct and that there are no collisions. In relation to this, I had changed the position of Html.BeginForm() and Html.EndForm() to wrap the contents instead of being wrapped. Paul, yours also worked. Thanks. I knew I had overlooked something of such small detail. My problem has been solved. Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: Please post the correct solution & then accept it so that the question is resolved.

Comment: google Fiddler, it will be your first result. Run it and you can see your request. You would've seen this field missing in the request, which points to a form/html issue. Also consider using the 'using' syntax for c# as is shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form was being wrapped like so:

```
Html.BeginWindow();
Html.BeginForm("edit_information", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "profile" });
<!-- other stuff goes in between here -->
Html.EndForm();
Html.EndWindow();
```

`Html.BeginWindow()` generates a table (a window) which is wrapped around the form. This had obviously caused parts of the form not to be POSTed properly.

Changed to:

```
Html.BeginForm("edit_information", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "profile" });
Html.BeginWindow();
<!-- other stuff goes in between here -->
Html.EndWindow();
Html.EndForm();
```

Bam! It worked again. This never occurred to me as I've done it before without any problems. I'm glad it's fixed. We all make mistakes.